# Swift : How do i create an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains an array inside them?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-dictionary

I am trying to load some data from my plist into an array. While declaring an array i did something like this

```
var natureList : [Dictionary] = [] as! [Dictionary]
```

I am getting this error
[image]

Here is my plist file
[image]

So how do i declare an array to load this data from my plist. ? I know its simple but this small thing is eating my head. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be declared as follows:

```
var natureList = [[String: Any]]()
```

or as @[LeoDabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) advised (thanks to him):

```
var natureList: [[String: Any]] = []
```

Means that `natureList` is an array of dictionaries of strings as keys and any as values.

If you are aiming to declare it using `Dictionary` -which is uanessacry-, you could also do it like this:

```
var natureList = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad F has the right answer, but just in case you (or a future reader) need to be more specific at some point here is how to break it down to a super specific type…

The inner most items in the plist (Summary: 1st flower, etc.) are all `[String: String]` because the key is a string and so is the associated value.

All of those inner most dictionaries are held in arrays so we add an extra set of brackets around our previous type: `[[String : String]]`.

Moving up a level all of those arrays are in a dictionary which means we add the key type, colon, and brackets: `[String: [[String : String]]]`

The dictionaries from the previous step are all held in an array which means we add another set of brackets to the outside leaving us with: `[[String: [[String : String]]]]`.

Again this level of detail is likely overkill but it is useful for demonstrating one way of breaking down a complex data structure by starting at the innermost level and working your way out. There are other ways of breaking down a structure like this  but this one is highly effective.